# If Else statement on T-SQL calculated column

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, t-sql

I have a table I'm creating for an app I'm making and want to populate a calculated column from an IF statement,I don't know how to write the T-SQL  for it and have looked for an answer but can't find

What i'm looking for is basically

```
IF (Close<=Open)
   [CloseLessEqualToOpen == Yes]
ELSE
   [CloseLessEqualToOpen == No]
```

T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LowFloatStocks] (
[Id]                   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date]                 DATE            NOT NULL,
[Ticker]               NCHAR (10)      NOT NULL,
[PreviousClose]        DECIMAL (4, 2)  DEFAULT ((4.00)) NOT NULL,
[OpeningPrice]         DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[GainPercent]          AS              (round(([High]-[OpeningPrice])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[GapPercent]           AS              (round(([OpeningPrice]-[PreviousClose])/[PreviousClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[Spike]                DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[1stSpike%]            AS              (round(([Spike]-[OpeningPrice])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[High]                 DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[HighPercent]          AS              (round(([High]-[PreviousClose])/[PreviousClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[Low]                  DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
[LowPercent]           AS              (round(([Low]-[PreviousClose])/[PreviousClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[Close]                DECIMAL (18, 2) DEFAULT ((4)) NOT NULL,
[ClosePercent]         AS              (round(([Close]-[PreviousClose])/[PreviousClose],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[CloseLessEqualToOpen] NCHAR (3)       NULL,
[CloseRed]             NCHAR (3)       NULL,
[ClosevHigh]           AS              (round(([High]-[Close])/[Close],(4))*(100)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[ClosevOpen]           AS              (round(([OpeningPrice]-[Close])/[OpeningPrice],(4))*(100.0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
[Catalyst]             NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
[Float]                DECIMAL (18, 3) NOT NULL,
[Dilution]             NCHAR (3)       NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator, not a function/expression. You need to use a `CASE` expression or `IIF`

Comment: why do you want to store as a computed colum?

Comment: Here is a [good example][1] of what you are trying to accomplish.



  [1]: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/27/sql-server-computed-column-conditions-case-statement/

Comment: What would be the argument against using it @Daniel A. White ?

Comment: @F.OLeary its a concern for querying and doesn’t promote normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get a single value to use in your statement:

```sql
DECLARE @Close   DECIMAL (18, 2);
SET @Close = (SELECT TOP 1 Close FROM [dbo].[LowFloatStocks]);
```

For above statement, you can also apply `WHERE` or any other clause based on your need.

Then use SQL [IF statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do your comparisons, this way:

```sql
IF(@Close <= Open) -- assuming that Open is declared somewhere else
    BEGIN
        -- Your logic here
        PRINT @Close
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       -- Your logic here
        PRINT @Close 
    END
```

Later you can update your Table this way:

```sql
UPDATE
    [dbo].[LowFloatStocks]
SET
    CloseLessEqualToOpen = ...
WHERE
    ...
```

---

However, there is also a more elegant solution in case if you want to make the calculation process happen automatically.

For that reason you can use [Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15#to-add-a-computed-column-when-creating-a-table):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LowFloatStocks]
(
       [Close]               DECIMAL (18, 2) DEFAULT ((4)) NOT NULL,
       [Open]                DECIMAL (18, 2) DEFAULT ((4)) NOT NULL,

       -- other columns declaration here

       [CloseLessEqualToOpen] AS CAST
       (
              CASE WHEN [Close] <= [Open] THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS NVARCHAR(10)
       )

)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you , I called it a calculated column,apologies to the other people if they misunderstood

Comment: `[CloseLessEqualToOpen] AS CAST (CASE WHEN [Close] <= [OpeningPrice] THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' ) PERSISTED NOT NULL,`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               @Arsen Khachaturyan I'm getting the syntax error near ')'  and cant figure out why?

Comment: @F.OLeary my apologies, I forgot to add the ending syntax there. Just edited the post, there should be no syntax errors now.